# How to set camera for page in Sketchup programmatically?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I am new in writing Sketchup plugins and I got problem. I know how to create page (scene) and camera, but I have no idea how to set the camera for the page. Any tips?

```
eye = [100, 100, 500]
target = [300, 300, 300]
up = [0, 0, 1]

pg_front = pages.add "front"
front_cam = Sketchup::Camera.new eye, target, up

# First idea, but it's not working
pg_front.camera = front_cam

# Second idea, but it's not working too
pg_front.use_camera = front_cam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use [`Camera#set`](https://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Camera.html#set-instance_method)?

```
pg_front.camera.set(front_cam)
```

I know very little about Sketchup, but you may have to update the page afterwards:

```
pg_front.update(1)
```

According to the docs of [`Page#update`](https://ruby.sketchup.com/Sketchup/Page.html#update-instance_method) the following update flags are available:

```
- 1 - Camera Location,
- 2 - Drawing Style,
- 4 - Shadow Settings,
- 8 - Axes Location,
- 16 - Hidden Geometry,
- 32 - Visible Layers,
- 64 - Active Section Planes.
```

If this isn't working, try disabling the camera before reassigning it, then enable it again (`pg_front.use_camera = true/false`).